# Obtaining offline access for web backend using Firebase for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am using Firebase SDK for authorising user on the Android app for a project which is on App Engine and already using many of the GCP and`G-Suite functionalities.

The web application relies on getting offline access to the user's Google Account.

The Android app is trying to use the same backend APIs that web front end is using. For this, I am sending the `ID token` of the user to backend.

The problem is that this ID token expires after some time and I am forced to re-authenticate the user to get the new ID token. Initially, I wanted it to not expire or generate a new ID token automatically on the Android app itself, but then I checked the [OAuth2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth) for this, which mentions the following statement -

> It is important that the Android app never attempt to exchange the
>   code for a refresh token on its own. This would require that the app
>   store the server's client ID and client secret. Including these in
>   your Android app is insecure, because apps can be easily decomposed.

The recommended flow is mentioned there, but I couldn't find anything which can help me do the same using the Firebase Android SDK.

Is it possible to get the `authorization code` using Firebase which can be later exchanged for refresh token by the backend? If yes, then can you point me to correct documentation or code example for the same?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. This doesn't seem to be a Firebase Auth issue. You want a way to get a Google authorization code and then exchange it for a long lived Google refresh token which will live on your backend server?

Comment: @bojeil Yes, but I want it using Firebase Auth and solutions which do not allow using Firebase Auth will not help me at all. That's the reason I have included the tag.

Comment: you need to take a step back and understand the difference between AUTHentication and AUTHorization. Android apps are authenticated very differently from web apps,